# How do you serve static pages at root while still supporting dynamic routes in Go?

Tags: http, go, server

How do you return HTML files as the default HTTP / path while still allowing specific child routes? I would like to serve a static `index.html` and some other HTML pages while still having specific routes passed to other `http.Handlers`.

In the example below I'm using the [httprouter mux](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter), but I'm interested in examples for `net/http` as well.

```golang
router := httprouter.New()
router.GET("/api", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {...})
router.ServeFiles("/*filepath", http.Dir(projectpath.Join("templates")))
```

```golang
router.GET("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    http.FileServer(http.Dir("templates")).ServeHTTP(w, r)
})
router.GET("/api", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {...})
```

Or using `net/http`

```golang
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("templates")))
http.Handle("/api", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){...})
http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
```

Comment: Your last example works and does what you want. What is your question?

Comment: @icza I am unable to serve files from `templates/*` other than `templates/index.html`

Comment: Here is a more complete example: https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/74cce1a97a28c08a18dc2c5f7d678490

Comment: That works for me. I put 2 files into `templates`: `index.html` and `list.html`. Querying `localhost:80/list.html` serves me the `list.html`.